# CRM 2011: Pre-Operation Entity References Without Names?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Long story short, I am trying to get the name of a lookup value using a plugin which executes on the pre-operation stage.

While the attribute/field in question contains an entity reference object, the object for some reason contains only the LogicalName and ID of the entity reference but not the name value (which is null)...

Does anyone know why this is and if there is a better workaround than doing a service call to the database just to retrieve the name field?

Comment: I think all queried `EntityReference`s do not retrieve the name, for whatever reason. Unfortunately, I say this only by experience and not because there's documentation on this topic (there isn't). So new database calls are the way to go.

Comment: What's frustrating is that if you update the lookup on update, the name will be overwritten after the plugin has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the Attributes of your entity:

```
string attribute_name = String.Empty;
Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

EntityReference _id = (EntityReference)entity["AttributeName"];

ColumnSet col = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "name" });
            var NameRetrieved = service.Retrieve("EntityName", _id.Id, col);
            if (NameRetrieved != null)
            {
                if (NameRetrieved.Attributes.Contains("name"))
                {
                   attribute_name = (string)productRetrieved["name"];
                }

                else
                {

                    attribute_name = "";

                }
            }
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said I was hoping to avoid having to do a service call in order to grab the name (since it's already populated) but I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid this =/

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the [Entity.FormattedValues collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.formattedvalues.aspx) contains the attribute that you need.